# Aggregation Time Series Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in elasticsearch whose records looks like:

```
data    
    {
      start: 20,
      userid: "123",
    },
    {
      start: 34,
      userid: "234",
    },
    {
      start: 8,
      userid: "123",
    },
    {
      start: 12,
      userid: "234",
    },
    {
      start: 18,
      userid: "345",
    }
```

"start" is a long (measure of time) and "userid" is a String. The data contains millions of user with multiple records for the same user.

```
Question:
```

I need all userid(s) who has their first record (sorted based on 'start') lies between times t1 and t2, e.g. between 10 and 15.

```
For userid 123, sorted times are: {8, 20}
For userid 234, sorted times are: {12, 34}
For userid 345, sorted times are: {18}
```

That's why it should return only userid "234", because just for this user, the first entry in the time array (sorted) is between 10 and 15.

```
Answer
234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the new [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) in ES 2.0.

To test it I set up a trivial index with the data you provided (I added a couple more to make it clear the aggregation was working):

```
DELETE /test_index

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"start":20,"userid":"123"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"start":34,"userid":"234"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"start":8,"userid":"123"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"start":12,"userid":"234"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"start":18,"userid":"345"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"start":8,"userid":"555"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"start":12,"userid":"555"}
```

Then I can get what you want with the following query:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "userid_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "userid"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "min_start": {
               "min": {
                  "field": "start"
               }
            },
            "min_start_filter": {
               "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "min_start": "min_start"
                  },
                  "script": "min_start >= 10 && min_start <= 15"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 7,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "userid_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "234",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "min_start": {
                  "value": 12
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/7427b87e878c23ce03bac199d6975434d66046f9

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using ES 1.7 but now I am upgrading it to ES2.0  I will test and let you know, but thanks again for the reply.